# Export from a standalone database to an embedded database

Tags: database

I have a two-part application, where there is a central database that is edited, and then at certain times, the data is released and distributed as its own application. I would like to use a standalone database for the central database (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) and then have a reliable export to an embedded database (probably SQLite) for distribution.

What tools/processes are available for such an export, or is it a practice to be avoided?

EDIT: A couple of additional pieces of information.  The distributed application should be able to run without having to connect to another server (ex: your spellchecker still works even you don't have internet), and I don't want to install a full DB server for read-only access to the data.

Comment: Why not replicate your data from the central database to some "slave"   databases?

Comment: @navi, I have added some additional information about why I don't want to replicate to the same type of database. Is there some sort of master-slave replication that gets around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want your clients to have read-access to the offline data it should not be that difficult to update your client-data manually.
A good practice would be to use the same product for the server database and the client database. You wouldn't have to write SQL-Statements twice since they use the same SOL-Dialect and same features.

- Firebird for example offers a server
  and an embedded version.
- Also Microsoft offers their MS SQL Server
  as a mobile version (compact edition) and there are
  also Synchronization services
  provided by Microsoft (good blog
  describing sync services in visual
  studio:
  http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2007/09/23/Sync-Services-for-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-3.5-in-Visual.aspx)
- MySQL has a product which is called "MySQLMobile" but I never actually used it.
- I can also recommend SQLite as an embedded database since it is very easy to use.

Depending on your bandwidth and data amount you could even download the whole database and delete the old one. (in Firebird for example only copy the database files and it will also work with the mobile version) Very easy - BUT you have to know if it will work for your scenario. If you have more data you will need something more flexible and sophisticated, only updating the data that really changed.